# monacaでメールアプリを開発することは可能でしょうか？

Tags: monaca, gmail, sendmail

はじめまして、よろしくお願いします。
monacaではメールアプリ開発できますか？
送信のみでもOKです。

Answer (score 1):

ここのサイトのチュートリアルでは不十分ですか？
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/monaca_api/cloud/mailer/